# Limit document type for file upload box in web form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, file-upload, file-type

Is there a way to set what file format types/filters through HTML or JavaScript?

I want the user to be able to select when he clicks the browse button on a web form. For example, I want to give him the option to select only JPG, GIF and PNG files for upload.

I know this is possible in Flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See *[input, accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input#attr-accept)* (HTML element):

> **accept**
>   If the value of the type attribute is file, this attribute 
>   indicates the types of files that the server accepts; otherwise it is
>   ignored. The value must be a comma-separated list of unique content
>   type specifiers:
>
> ```
>     A valid MIME type with no extensions
>     audio/* representing sound files HTML5
>     video/* representing video files HTML5
>     image/* representing image files HTML5
> ```

---

[Or see example here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/KES5e/).

Comment: This did not work for me even when i followed what quoted page said and used javascript

Comment: Sorry that was an obsolete attrib on the form element.. I was linking you to the wrong site.